# Connection to PostgreSQL disconnects every hour regardless of activity

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, connectivity

I'm monitoring my PostgreSQL clients using a periodic `netstat -an | grep 5432 | grep EST` to check the `ESTABLISHED` status of the connection every 5 minutes. I have noticed that all of the connections become `TIME_WAIT` after around minutes, and then a new connection is re-opened (the client port changes), forming a new `ESTABLISHED` connection. This behavior persists regardless of the status or activity of the postgres client.

Any thoughts on what might be causing this recurring reconnection on the clients? I've tried setting the `tcp_keepalives_idle` to no avail.

Comment: You should consult the logs of the database server and the application. Perhaps there is a timeout on the server (but that would *not* apply to idle connections unless they have an open transaction), perhaps it is a connection pool, perhaps it is an ill-configured firewall.

Comment: The description fits the clients themselves initiating these reconnections.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Turns out you're right! It does use a connection pool (HikariCP), and the maxLifeTime and idleTimeout configurations are causing the reconnection. Fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it uses a connection pool by [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP). The default behavior of the maxLifetime and idleTimeout configurations are causing the reconnection. Setting both configurations to 0 disables them and removes the reconnecting issue.

Shoutout to this [comment](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246336/connection-to-postgresql-disconnects-every-hour-regardless-of-activity?noredirect=1#comment486182_246336) for helping me understand my problem.